# How to diagnose the Slow fSync, Slow write, slow background cluster warning/notice in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

I am getting this info, notice and warning in my MarkLogic errorlog file.
What does this mean and how to diagnose it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let me start out by saying, I would open a support ticket for this. Fsync is a system level call to the drive and its showing that its take a long time to write to the file system. How often are you seeing this and is it on all the nodes?

I'd also suggest taking a look at this knowledge base article, https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/508/0/understanding-slow-infrastructure-notification. It talks about Slow fsync and explains why you might have gotten it.

Comment: I have already gone throw the knowledgebase article but didn't understood much to be honest. Yup its on all nodes and seen very often. I did ML restart initially, it works for an hour then again throwing same warnings. I restarted like 15 times but still same behavior.

Comment: Restarting isn’t going to fix this. It has to do with the disks and the ability of the system on each node to be able to to write to the underline drives at a speed that is fast enough to keep up with the requirements of Marklogic‘ check of a forest to see if it had update or not. It’s a very inexpensive call so I’d start by looking at your drive. A support case would help with this as they’d be able to look at the setup and help resolve this issue for you.

Comment: Would also like to add that this question isn’t one that can easily be answered here. It’s going to require a dialogue and looking into the logs and configuration of the systems that you are talking about.